# Store incomplete date in MySQL date field

Tags: mysql, date

I want to offer the user the possibility to introduce dates that are incomplete (for example just the year 2005, or Jan 1998) but also complete dates with year, month, day. Can I accomplish this using a single date field in the DB?

I have tried `UPDATE tableA SET mydate = '2001-00-00'` and it seems to work (no errors) but I'm not sure if this is correct. Internally I assume a timestamp is used so how can MySQL represent those 0's?

Comment: What do you get when you query `SELECT mydate FROM tableA` ?

Comment: The correct value i.e. 2001-00-00. My worry is just that I'm exploiting some none standard behaviour that relies on some trick that might some day break or not work in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a small note in the [documentation for the DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) about MySQL allowing incomplete dates:

> Ranges for the month and day specifiers begin with zero due to the
>   fact that MySQL permits the storing of incomplete dates such as
>   '2014-00-00'.

As pointed out by [@wonk0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882788/store-incomplete-date-in-mysql-date-field#6882825), MySQL will sets invalid dates to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` when `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` is not set.  However, even when `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` is not set, inserting a valid year with month and day set to zero does not appear to trigger this behaviour - at least not in my testing (MySQL 5.1.54-1ubuntu4).  I have used this feature before without any problem, but I have so far been unable to find any more detailed documentation that describes this behaviour in full.

Date/Time comparisons also appear to work as expected: for example, `2011-01-00 > 2011-00-00` and `2011-00-01 > 2011-00-00` do as you would expect.

**UPDATE**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882788/store-incomplete-date-in-mysql-date-field#6882825) (by another Mike) to a similar question.  It points to an extract from *The Definitive Guide to MySQL 5*:

> In older versions of MySQL, the DATE and DATETIME data types did only
>   a limited amount of type checking.  Values between 0 and 12 for
>   months, and 0 and 31 for days were generally allowed.  However, it is
>   the responsibility of the client program to provide correct data. (For
>   example, 0 is a permissible value for a month or day, in order to
>   provide the possibility of storing incomplete or unknown data.)
>
> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.2, there is a more thorough validation, so
>   that only valid data can be stored.  Still allowed are the month and
>   day values 0, as well as the date 0000-00-00.

Comment: Is the assumption that a timestamp is used to store the date therefore incorrect? Because I don't see how you can represent 2011-00-00 as a timestamp.

Comment: @Omar Kohl: Yes, I think that assumption is incorrect.  A `TIMESTAMP` has a smaller range than a `DATETIME`.  A `DATETIME` uses 8 bytes, whereas a `TIMESTAMP` uses 4 bytes.  See [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#id918335)

Comment: Excellent answer, the best I have found searching far and wide.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that on MySQL 5.7+ this behavior is disallowed by default: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you used a date field then you should expect those 0s. One way you can get rid of them is by using the `varchar` selection rather. However, it is better to use a date field since thats what is stored there.

If you have to allow users to enter an incomplete date then it has to be a `varchar` and in that case you can format the input with your script and store in that column

Comment: That would be my last resort. Of course having things in date format is always nicer for ordering etc.

Comment: yeah so rather than allowing users to format the date, i advice you just allow sql to format the current `datetimestamp` there

Answer (score 1):

Storing parts of dates depends on the sql mode MySQL is running in. Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html, especially about invalid dates in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates.

Comment: "ALLOW_INVALID_DATES: Do not perform full checking of dates. Check only that the month is in the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31."
In this case it doesn't apply because neither month nor day are in that range... (00 both)

Comment: `Check only that the month is in the range from 1 to 12 and the day is in the range from 1 to 31` Why does this allow a month or a day of 0 ?