# MySQL store month & year only

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to do it in MySQL or what would be better approach than making the fieldtype **varchar**?

```
Output should be like
06/2014
```

Related: [mysql datatype to store month and year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134497/mysql-datatype-to-store-month-and-year-only)

Comment: Yes, but then they would not sort in order (as dates).

Comment: If you want to keep integrity (and maybe sanity) why not just use 2 INT columns for year and month. You can then format the output when you query the tables.

Comment: @unutbu, sorting is not necessary in my current scenario.

Comment: @Frazz, using 2 columns is a way infact but using 1 would be comfortable for me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping you have a really good reason to do this; you can set a default day (preferably the first day) for your date and just make the months different.

```
STR_TO_DATE('06/01/2014', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

I would recommend that you store the entire date and just use the Month() and Year() functions as you can still run queries.

Comment: But this leaves a lot up to the application. Foreign keys, uniqueness and integrity in general, if required, are moved from the server layer to the application layer.

Comment: @Ramie, thank you for your quick response. You are right in this but isn't making fieldtype varchar to save "06/2014", better?

Comment: I guess saving full date and then using MONTH() and YEAR() would do just fine. :)