# What is an appropriate value to store in a DATE MySQL variable if only month and year are known?

Tags: mysql, date

Suppose I have a MySQL variable `date_stored` of date datatype. I have only the month and year for a particularly date data to be stored in `date_stored`. No day information is given. Are there guidelines on what to store in `date_stored` if only month and year are known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL manual says that partial dates can be stored.
Month and day Ranges specifiers begin with zero because MySQL permits incomplete dates storing such as `'2015-00-00'` or `'2015-10-00'`.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

So if day part is not given you can still store it as `YYYY-MM-00` 
e.g `'2015-10-00'`

Also See below related posts.

[Store incomplete date in MySQL date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882788/store-incomplete-date-in-mysql-date-field)

[mysql datatype to store month and year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134497/mysql-datatype-to-store-month-and-year-only)

[SQL DataType - How to store a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696506/sql-datatype-how-to-store-a-year)